# Twig_Error_Runtime on Local Dev Environment

Tags: installation

Trying to set up craft on local environment and getting the following error once running mysql. Any clue what usually causes twig_error_runtime?

```
Twig_Error_Runtime

Method "bust" for object "Craft\CraftVariable" does not exist in "_layout" at line 66 (/Users/username/Sites/site.com/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php:485)

#0 /Users/username/Sites/site.com/craft/app/etc/templating/BaseTemplate.php(41): Twig_Template->getAttribute(Object(Craft\CraftVariable), 'bust', Array, 'any', false, false)
#1 /Users/username/Sites/site.com/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/f7/b1/be6fe94a8e6c7ce48ecb00086d0a2ebde7cc24cc43eec4a6ba82fa4a24c9.php(128): Craft\BaseTemplate->getAttribute(Object(Craft\CraftVariable), 'bust', Array)
#2 /Users/username/Sites/site.com/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(313): __TwigTemplate_f7b1be6fe94a8e6c7ce48ecb00086d0a2ebde7cc24cc43eec4a6ba82fa4a24c9->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#3 /Users/username/Sites/site.com/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(287): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#4 /Users/username/Sites/site.com/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/44/d5/7fc586931d2e13dfcd02f8209765153f695b63c7cf7dd78afa05d76029c4.php(27): Twig_Template->display(Array, Array)
#5 /Users/username/Sites/site.com/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(313): __TwigTemplate_44d57fc586931d2e13dfcd02f8209765153f695b63c7cf7dd78afa05d76029c4->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#6 /Users/username/Sites/site.com/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(287): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#7 /Users/username/Sites/site.com/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(298): Twig_Template->display(Array)
#8 /Users/username/Sites/site.com/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(293): Twig_Template->render(Array)
#9 /Users/username/Sites/site.com/craft/app/services/TemplatesService.php(223): Twig_Environment->render('404', Array)
#10 /Users/username/Sites/site.com/craft/app/controllers/BaseController.php(74): Craft\TemplatesService->render('404', Array)
#11 /Users/username/Sites/site.com/craft/app/controllers/TemplatesController.php(201): Craft\BaseController->renderTemplate('404', Array)
#12 /Users/username/Sites/site.com/craft/app/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(49): Craft\TemplatesController->actionRenderError()
#13 /Users/username/Sites/site.com/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#14 /Users/username/Sites/site.com/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(286): CController->runAction(Object(CInlineAction))
#15 /Users/username/Sites/site.com/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(265): CController->runActionWithFilters(Object(CInlineAction), Array)
#16 /Users/username/Sites/site.com/craft/app/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(282): CController->run('renderError')
#17 /Users/username/Sites/site.com/craft/app/framework/base/CErrorHandler.php(368): CWebApplication->runController('templates/rende...')
#18 /Users/username/Sites/site.com/craft/app/framework/base/CErrorHandler.php(351): CErrorHandler->renderError()
#19 /Users/username/Sites/site.com/craft/app/framework/base/CErrorHandler.php(218): CErrorHandler->renderException()
#20 /Users/username/Sites/site.com/craft/app/etc/errors/ErrorHandler.php(128): CErrorHandler->handleException(Object(Craft\HttpException))
#21 /Users/username/Sites/site.com/craft/app/framework/base/CErrorHandler.php(131): Craft\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(Craft\HttpException))
#22 /Users/username/Sites/site.com/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(740): CErrorHandler->handle(Object(CExceptionEvent))
#23 [internal function]: CApplication->handleException(Object(Craft\HttpException))
#24 {main}
```

Answer (score 2):

Was simply root password in DB changing since last loading up environment. Threw some more errors to finally see database connection issues and just had to update db.php to fix. Leaving this here in case anyone else has issues.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your `_layout` template code? It looks like you may be trying to use a variable like `{{ craft.bust }}` which doesn’t exist in your local environment.

Comment: Missing plugin perhaps?

Comment: Hmmm... If i remote the {{ craft.bust }} variable it throws and error for `The filter "auto_link" does not exist in "_layout" at line 68 ` for the {{ siteName }} link. Sounds like something isn't running. Just restarted mysql and php no change.